# Libnet missing some defines flags

Tags: linux, libpcap, libnet

Once I've installed libnet1-dev, check out the configuration settings by issues "libnet-config --defines", but it is no way to find "-DLIBNET_LIL_ENDIAN" flag.

```
libnet-config --defines
-D_BSD_SOURCE -D__BSD_SOURCE -D__FAVOR_BSD -DHAVE_NET_ETHERNET_H
```

Then I've return back to my already extracted directory in "Libnet-1.0.2a" and installed it against where I found as below. It will missing certains defined flags as in above.

```
libnet-config --defines
-DLIBNET_LIL_ENDIAN
```

My question is that weather to have any way to install libnet contained together with "-D_BSD_SOURCE -D__BSD_SOURCE -D__FAVOR_BSD -DHAVE_NET_ETHERNET_H -DLIBNET_LIL_ENDIAN".
Thanks to anyone for helps. FYI, I'm using ubuntu x64.

Answer (score 0):

This question doesn't make any sense. Can you describe what you are trying to do, and why you think you should define these macros?

You should not define LIBNET_LIL_ENDIAN on any platform, it is defined in libnet.h.

libnet1-dev on ubuntu 13.10 on x64, for example, defines it:

```
% grep ENDIAN /usr/include/libnet.h                                  │
#define LIBNET_LIL_ENDIAN 1
```

You also mention using libnet 1.02a, released in 2001... try a libnet release that's less than a decade old:  http://sourceforge.net/projects/libnet-dev/files/